# How should I map same named jsp files from different folders in my web.xml file?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, deployment, mapping, web.xml

I am new to tomcat and java. I am facing a little problem. In web-apps folder I have a TestSite named folder which consists of index.jsp, WEB-INF folder and pages folder. The pages folder consist of another index.jsp page. How should I map same named jsp files in different folders in my web.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSPs do not need to be mapped. The JspServlet in the container does that already for you. Refer to them as-is in the webapp folder.

Comment: then why we use <jsp-file> tag in web.xml?

Comment: To map a jsp file to a specific path instead of a servlet. But this is bad practice, JSPs are crappy views and not controllers.